# In a macro transformer, is it possible to lift a definition to the top level?

Tags: macros, lisp, acl2

In an ACL2 macro transformer, is it possible to lift a function definition to the top level?

I'm trying to design a macro `let-map` that can define functions like `map-double` below when given a `double` function.

If I only cared about the top level, I could do this with a `define-map` macro. However, I want this macro to be able to be able to called in a context nested within another expression. So for example:

```
(defunc double (x)
  :input-contract (rationalp x)
  :output-contract (rationalp (double x))
  (* 2 x))

(let-map map-double double
  (map-double (list 1 2 3)))
;(LIST 2 4 6)

;; I would want nested calls to work as well:
(let-map double-all-1d double
  (let-map double-all-2d double-all-1d
    (double-all-2d (list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5) (list 6)))))
;(LIST (LIST 2 4 6) (LIST 8 10) (LIST 12))
```

I want the `let-map` macro to define a function `map-double`, and then return the result of the body, in this case calling `(map-double (list 1 2 3))`. I tried defining this in terms of `flet`, but my `map-double` function is recursive, so `flet` doesn't work.

```
(defmacro let-map (map-f f body)
  `(flet ((,map-f (lst)
                  (cond ((endp lst) (list))
                        (t (cons (,f (first lst))
                                 ; doesn't work because
                                 ; `flet` doesn't support recursion
                                 (,map-f (rest lst)))))))
     ,body))
```

I would use `labels`, but it's not supported in ACL2.

So to allow recursion, I want to lift the definition of `map-f` (which is `map-double` in my use of this macro) to the top level. Is this possible in the ACL2 macro system?

In a system like racket, I would use a function like [`syntax-local-lift-expression`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-local-lift-expression%29%29) to do this. So is there an analogous form in ACL2?

Comment: I don't know enough of ACL2, but wouldn't expanding into a `defun` work?

Comment: @coredump What do you mean? I can't expand to a `defun` directly, because I want `let-map` to work in a nested expression context. So what I want to do is lift the `defun` to the top level from within the macro transformer.

Comment: Couldn't you use `labels` instead of `flet`, then?

Comment: @Svante I hadn't heard of `labels`, and I couldn't find it in the ACL2 documentation. Apparently it exists in lisp, but not in ACL2. The error message, when I try to use it, says that it is in the main lisp package, but it doesn't have a function or macro definition in ACL2.

Comment: So to simulate a `labels`-like form, I want to know if it's possible to lift function definitions to the top level from inside a macro transformer.